# Upgrading my 2007 iMac

Tags: upgrade

I was considering purchasing a new Mac Mini as a way of upgrading my 2007 iMac.  If this is not possible, I'll probably just purchase a new iMac.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you hoping to use the iMac as a monitor for the mini?

Comment: Yes, along with the mouse, keyboard and CD drive.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be abble to use the iMac as a screen.

The [Target Display Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924) is only supported by iMacs since the late 2009 models.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I'll need to purchase another iMac.

Comment: Then mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark on the left of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the IMac as a direct screen but you can use Remote Desktop to access other machines e.g. the new Mac Mini.

Remote Desktop will be a slower screen and I think does not remote audio.

Comment: Thanks, I'm satisfied now that a new iMac will be my best option.

Comment: That was my decision in the same case